# Adding formatted date to custom grids

Tags: javascript, sdk, rally

I'm working on a custom grid in Rally to create a table of Portfolio Items in my Project.  One field I'm trying to expose is Planned Start Date.  When used as-is, it returns datetime in the following format - "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.xxxZ".  I've been trying to use the rally.sdk.util.DateTime.format( date(), "yyyy-MM-dd") function to just return the date instead of the whole thing when creating my rowInfo name/value pairs to add to my table, but it's not working.

Any ideas?

```
var tbCfgTable = {
    columns: [{  
        key: 'ID',  
        width: "20%"  
    },{
        key: 'Name',
        width: "4%"
    },{
        key: 'Planned Start',
        width: "4%"
    },{
        key: 'Planned End',
        width: "3%"
    }]
};
gTable = new rally.sdk.ui.Table(tbCfgTable);

var nbrPis = theResults.pisQueryKey.length;
for (var ndx = 0; ndx < nbrPis; ndx++){
    aPi = theResults.pisQueryKey[ndx];
    // populate planned schedule rows
    aRowInfo = {
            'ID': aPi.Name,
            'Name': aPi.Name,
            'Planned Start': aPi.PlannedStartDate,
            'Planned End': aPi.PlannedEndDate
            };
    gTable.addRow(aRowInfo);
}
```

Comment: If you can post a little snippet of the code you currently have that probably would help us help you more. =-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're really close to getting it- all you need to do is parse the date string into a date object first and then format it.

```
//function to format date
function formatDate(dateString) {
    if(!dateString) { return ''; }

    return rally.sdk.util.DateTime.format(
        rally.sdk.util.DateTime.fromIsoString(dateString, true), 'yyyy-MM-dd');
}

//build your table rows as usual, calling formatDate for each date field
aRowInfo = {
    'ID': aPi.Name,
    'Name': aPi.Name,
    'Planned Start': formatDate(aPi.PlannedStartDate),
    'Planned End': formatDate(aPi.PlannedEndDate)
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I've tried to do this, but I'm now getting a TypeError on this code.  Seems like it's returning a string, which is what you're expecting in the RowInfo, so I'm not sure where the mismatch is.

Comment: You probably have some PI's that don't have one or both of the PlannedStart/EndDate fields set.  In formatDate first check to see if dateString is defined and if not just return empty string.  I updated the example above to reflect...